# How to get the site url for Facebook API on device? [Cordova Project]

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm using facebook API in my cordova project for the first time, I'm trying to get only name and picture from user's facebook, so what I but in settings -> Site URL http://localhost:4400/ and everything works well. The problem is when I test my application on Device showing me a message "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain"

in PC window.location returns (http://localhost:4400/)

in Device window.location returns (file:///andriod_asset/www/sign.html) so I cant use it because URL must begin with http or https

any solutions or explains, please ?

Comment: seems to be a well known issue, you can find many links about it with google: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/379

Comment: nothing helps, thanks by the way

Comment: Are you using github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/379  or Facebook javascript api ?

Comment: facebook javascript API